# change code from C++ TO C# use at-commend

Tags: c#, c++, at-command

I have to do a small application that has to send a USSD Message and receive its answer. After some investigations over the net I use "AT Commands". I use C# to develop a windows application.

This is some simple code which I use it to send USSD

`Port.Write("AT+CUSD=0,\"*100*1*#\",15\r\n");`

And it receives answer BUT that massage is needed to close!
I do not know how to close it !
I found some code to help me in the net written in C++

```
User::LeaveIfError(StartC32());

RCommServ commServer;
CleanupClosePushL( commServer );
User::LeaveIfError(commServer.Connect());

_LIT(KCsyName, "dataport");
User::LeaveIfError(commServer.LoadCommModule(KCsyName));

_LIT(KDataPort, "DATAPORT::1");
TBuf<20> port(KDataPort);
RComm commW;
CleanupClosePushL( commW );

User::LeaveIfError(commW.Open(commServer, port, ECommShared));

TBuf8<128> atCommand;
atCommand.Append(_L8("AT+CUSD=0,\""));
atCommand.Append(aUssdCode);
atCommand.Append(_L8("\",15\r\n"));

TRequestStatus callStatus;
commW.Write(callStatus, _L8("ATE0\r\n"));
User::WaitForRequest(callStatus);
User::LeaveIfError(callStatus.Int());
User::After(1000); 

commW.Write(callStatus, atCommand);
User::WaitForRequest(callStatus);
User::LeaveIfError(callStatus.Int());
User::After(1000); 

TBuf<128> temp;
temp.Copy(atCommand);
CEikonEnv::Static()->InfoWinL(_L("Message Sended:"),temp);

if(callStatus.Int() == KErrNone)
{
  TBuf8<160> replyBuf; 
  commW.Read(callStatus, TTimeIntervalMicroSeconds32(10000000), replyBuf);
  User::WaitForRequest(callStatus);
  User::LeaveIfError(callStatus.Int());
  User::After(1000); 

  TBuf<160> msg;
  msg.Copy(replyBuf);

  CEikonEnv::Static()->InfoWinL(_L("Message Received:"),msg);

  User::LeaveIfError(replyBuf.Compare(atCommand)==0);      
}else
 {
  User::Leave(callStatus.Int());
 }

CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy( &commW );
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy( &commServer );
```

I want someone help me to change some code from C++ to C#
Jest I want tow thing

First, I want code to stop the application till I get the answered massage
Ex.

`User::WaitForRequest(callStatus);`

Second, I want to make a button to close that massage 
Ex.

`CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy( &commW );
 CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy( &commServer );`

I hope my issue is clear for you
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the C# SerialPort class:

```
 using (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1"))
        {
            port.Open();
            port.WriteLine("AT+CUSD=0,\"");
            var result = port.ReadLine();               
        }
```

this will automatically Close and Dispose the serial line after use. If you want a button to do that for you make sure you call both those methods to terminate the serial port stream.

Comment: thank you for your answer
I try to use the code as: 
`    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port = new   System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM7"))
            {
                port.Open();
                port.WriteLine("AT+CUSD=0,\"*147*1#\",15\r\n");
                var result = port.ReadLine();
            }
        }`
when i press the button 2time the message is not Close

The message have an option Ex. 1.Eng 2.other
and by press the button more than one to send USSD it will not send as new USSD Comend!It is chose lang